# Goroutines memory leak

Tags: go, memory-leaks, channel, goroutine

**UPD:** Refactored code, nothing change

I'm have memory leak in this function but i don't know where.

```
func CheckProxySOCKS(prox string, c chan QR) (err error) {

    //Sending request through proxy
    dialer, _ := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", prox, nil, proxy.Direct)
    timeout := time.Duration(5 * time.Second)
    httpClient := &http.Client{Timeout: timeout, Transport: &http.Transport{Dial: dialer.Dial}}
    res, err := httpClient.Get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")

    if err != nil {

        c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: false}
        return
    }

    _, err = ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: true}
    return
}
```

Here i called it

```
for _, proxy := range splitedProxies {
    go code.CheckProxySOCKS(proxy, respChan)
}

for range splitedProxies {
    r := <-respChan
    if r.Res {
        checkedProxiesArray = append(checkedProxiesArray, r.Addr)
    }
}
```

After 3-4 cycle i'v got more than 40k goroutines(i'v check it by `runtime.NumGoroutine()`). After start app used around 100mb after 4 cycle more than 1GB

[Github](https://github.com/trigun117/ProxyGrabber) repo with all code

Comment: You should check your error when you call `proxy.SOCKS5`

Comment: Also the docs say you should close the response from calling `Get`. Not sure if it's your problem at the moment but you might want to bind that variable and call its `Close` method.

Comment: I want to say something stronger than the previous comment. The application **must** close the response response body when Get returns successfully.  This is one cause of the issues you are seeing and possibly the only cause.

Comment: Close the response body and don't create a new client for each request (or more precisely, a new Transport). Each Transport maintains its own connection pool, and since you don't disable keep-alive, you end up with lots of idle connections that are never reused.

Comment: @Peter i changed code like this `httpClient := &http.Client{Timeout: timeout, Transport: &http.Transport{DisableKeepAlives: true, Dial: dialer.Dial}}` but it couldn't help. Or i'm doing it wrong? Maybe you have an example?

Comment: I think he means to move that line to else where, so it's created once and used by CheckProxySOCKS function as many times, without re-creating it each time.

Answer (score 2):

You're not always closing the connection, and you're using a new Client *and* Transport every request. If you discard the transport, you discard any connections in the idle pool, leaking those resources.

From the [`http.Transport` docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport)

> By default, Transport caches connections for future re-use. This may leave many open connections when accessing many hosts. This behavior can be managed using Transport's CloseIdleConnections method and the MaxIdleConnsPerHost and DisableKeepAlives fields.
>
> Transports should be reused instead of created as needed. Transports are safe for concurrent use by multiple goroutines.

Always close the response body when there is no error, and always reuse the transport.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in not closing the response body, in this line:

```
_, err := httpClient.Get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")
```

get the response variable and close the body in defer, like this:

```
r, err := httpClient.Get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json")
if err != nil {
    c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: false}
    return
}
defer r.Body.Close()

c <- QR{Addr: prox, Res: true}
```

in the docs `The client must close the response body when finished with it:` [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)

Comment: i'm refactored code as you suggest but nothing change

Comment: can you please move: `    res.Body.Close()` above the ioutil.ReadAll, it won't fix the memory leak, but just to be sure. Don't forget to add `defer` before it.